# Programmatically change Keyboard Layout

Tags: powershell

I work in a Swiss company environment with `de-CH` as the standard keyboard-layout, while using a `de-DE` keyboard.

I'm able to change my keyboard settings manually to the preferred `de-DE`-layout, set it as standard and and assign a shortscut.

However: somehow my settings disappear after an arbitrary amount of time (might have something to do with updates the administrators run), so I have to repeat this every couple of days.

[This](http://www.capri-technology.be/en/blog/set-keyboard-layout-powershell) suggests there's an easy way to change the keyboard-layout with Powershell in Win 8:

`Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList DE-DE`

Sadly, I work with Win 7. Therefore, I get the following error message, which, as a Powershell-dummy, I interpret as a plain statement that the cmdlet doesn't exist in Win 7:

```
PS C:\Users\b036081> Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList DE-DE
Set-WinUserLanguageList : The term 'Set-WinUserLanguageList' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path 
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList DE-DE
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-WinUserLanguageList:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Now, is there another comparably simple way in Powershell? Or even in C++, C#, Batch, VB...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try this: http://superuser.com/questions/395818/how-to-change-keyboard-layout-via-command-line-cmd-exe-on-windows-xp-7

Comment: P/Invoking to [LoadKeyboardLayout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms646305) and wrapping that as a cmdlet should do it. But since your question is about a *comparably simple way*, that would not be it (but someone could write it).

Comment: Ask your company IT administrator…

Comment: @JeroenMostert will look into that if anything else fails, however, I got next to no idea of creating ps-cmdlets. then again, excited to learn new stuff. Thanks for your idea

Comment: @scotru tried it without producing any errors when attempting to set my Keyboard to `en-EN`. However, no noticeable effect

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this command

```
powershell -command "Set-WinUserLanguageList -Force 'en-US'"
```

or

```
powershell -command "Set-WinUserLanguageList -Force 'fr-FR'"
```

Comment: As stated in the original question, PS doesn't recognize `Set-WinUserLanguageList`.

Comment: This answer is useful; many of us are not using Windows 7 any more. Hopefully not the OP as well. :-)

Comment: For `Windows 7` installing `Windows Management Framework 5.1` will not help you (((

Answer (score 3):

I think you can change it in the registry.

There is a registry key under:

HKU:\.Default\Keyboard Layout\Preload\

Easily change it to the country code 00000407 - de-de in the registry, that should solve your problem.

But first you have to create a new PS-Drive, to "mount" the "HKEY_USERS" from registry.

```
$psdrive = New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKU -Root HKEY_USERS

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKU:\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload\" -Name 1 -Value "00000407"

$psdrive | Remove-PSDrive
```

Comment: I like the idea and I guess that usually works, however: I'm not allowed to change that registry entry (no admin rights). Ofc you couldn't know that!

Comment: No need to create a psdrive: just use `Registry::HKEY_USERS` instead of `HKU:`.

Comment: The language value 00000407 should be enclosed in double quotes to be a string, otherwize 407 would be as int value.

To make changes in registry, one should run PS script under admin credentials.

Answer (score 3):

#### Option 1: WinDefaultInputMethodOverride

You can override the default input method. The `InputTip` is the combination of *language indetifier* and *keyboard identifier*. ([Default Input Profiles (Input Locales) in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-input-locales-for-windows-language-packs))

```
Set-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride -InputTip '0409:00000409'
```

#### Option 2: Update Registry

For this, you have to be allowed to change the registry.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload\' -Name 1 -Value 00010409
```

#### Identifiers

A list of **keyboard identifiers** can be found on [Keyboard Identifiers and Input Method Editors for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values). In the registry you can find the ones available on your system. **Language identifiers** can be found on [Available languages for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/available-language-packs-for-windows)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layouts\'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change current input language via .NET class, like this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'
[System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage]::CurrentInputLanguage = [System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage]::InstalledInputLanguages | ? { $_.Culture -eq 'ru-RU' }
```

Comment: On Windows 10 with PowerShell 5 this fails with `Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage].` unless preceded by `Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'`.  Something about the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace makes me think this isn't going to be very effective with PowerShell...

Comment: It is all depends on the task. Some people might have restrictions to edit the registry. This is just another way to do this.

Comment: @Kirill Pashkov, while I am not getting an error message, I can't notice any effect when playing around with it for a bit. This, however, could have something to do with restrictions in my user profile. Still: thanks a lot for that alternative approach!

Comment: Note: this is only for setting the current input language _for the current thread_. Upstream documentation for the `System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage` class is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.currentinputlanguage?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_InputLanguage_CurrentInputLanguage

Answer (score 1):

Run this below command in PowerShell window:

```
Set-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride -InputTip "0409:00000409"
```

This command sets the default input method override to English (United States) - US.

[Another Input Profiles (Input Locales) here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-input-locales-for-windows-language-packs)

Answer (score -1):

While my system automatically resets to a `de-CH` layout IF i set any other language as default, I can still cycle to my prefered keyboard layout with `ALT`+`SHIFT`+`1`... just as long as i dont try to delete the non-used `de-CH` entry.

The Powershell approach doesn't seem to work with my system.