# Can't send input in English when another language is selected using LuaMacros

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, winapi, lua

I am using this code in [LuaMacros program](https://github.com/me2d13/luamacros) in order to simulate the "q" key press. I need it to always type the english character, even if my secondary keyboard language is selected.

```
lmc_send_input(81,0,4)
lmc_send_input(81,0,6)
```

It really prints ";" instead of "q" when greek language is selected, which is something that happens when you also type with physical keyboard.

1. I need to use latin characters only . Is it possible?
2. Or else is it possible for me to detect the current selected keyboard language and then change it on keypress?
3. Is it possible to use C++ inside lua?

I could use something like

```
string lang = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture.Name;
```

or

```
string StrCurrentLang = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
```

so that I could check which is the user language and then change it. You can find more here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277 ... e-computer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27747176)

Is this possible?
Can you please provide a workaround on this?

Comment: I have fixed the link in the question, noted above. As the link is for a C# tag, and you're not using one yourself, why didn't you search for [Powershell answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41096875)? as you're using that tag yourself.

Comment: I thought it was done using powershell or batch script. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Did you actually click on the link in my last comment? As you have made no mention of it, it does now feel like it was an inconvenience for me to include it!