# Changing keyboard layout in PowerShell for multiple languages

Tags: powershell, automation, windows-10

This question is an extended version of [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096875/programmatically-change-keyboard-layout)

In windows-10 I need to programatically add 3 languages: en-US, SV, RU.

It works well with the following command:

```
Set-WinUserLanguageList en-US, sv, ru -Force
```

The problem is that this way system adds the **default** keyboard layout for every language, whereas i need a different layout for russian - **0419:A0000419** (preinstalled)

Tried to solve the puzzle with this:

```
  $rusLang = New-WinUserLanguageList ru
  $rusLang[0].InputMethodTips.Clear()
  $rusLang[0].InputMethodTips.Add('0419:A0000419') # required layout
  Set-WinUserLanguageList en-US, sv, $rusLang
```

It didn't do the trick. Failed with *InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-WinUserLanguageList], ParameterBindingException*

I do not care whether the RU language will be added with the desired *InputMethodTips*, or this param is overwritten after the `Set-WinUserLanguageList en-US, sv, ru -Force`

How can it be acheived?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try use this code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-input-locales-for-windows-language-packs)

```
Dism /Image:"C:\mount\windows" /Set-InputLocale:042d:0000040a
Dism /Image:"C:\mount\windows" /Set-InputLocale:0411:{03B5835F-F03C-411B-9CE2-AA23E1171E36}{A76C93D9-5523-4E90-AAFA-4DB112F9AC76}
Dism /Image:"C:\mount\windows" /Set-InputLocale:id-ID
Dism /Image:"C:\mount\windows" /Set-AllIntl:fr-FR
```

Or you can use like this:

```
  $Lang = New-WinUserLanguageList en-US #you cant add all language at time(of course you can piping it)
  $Lang.Add("sv") #you must add it simple
  $Lang.Add("ru")
  $Lang[2].InputMethodTips.Clear()
  $Lang[2].InputMethodTips.Add('0419:A0000419') # required layout
  Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList $Lang #input must be in format System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage>
```