# Single Keyboard Different Layouts

Tags: powershell, keyboard

I use "English" language and I want to adding more keyboard layouts in that language, I can achieve this with "UI" but I want to make it with powershell. In PS, I ran this but it didn't not work, and only apply for keyboard layout for selected language.

```
Set-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride -InputTip "0409:d0010409"
```

[image]

So, How can I add more than one keyboard layout of different countries to a language and how can I download it?

**Expected Input List**

```
<language>:<layout1,layout2,layout3> and so on..
```

Comment: I commend to your attention [Microsoft Learn/Microsoft Ignite on `Install-Language`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/languagepackmanagement/install-language?view=windowsserver2019-ps). You might also find [this StackOverflow question (and its answers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096875/programmatically-change-keyboard-layout) to be of interest.

Comment: My question not same, it is single language single keyboard or single language multiple different keyboard, however my question related on single keyboard for multiple layouts, they are not same @JeffZeitlin